# Is MMAP what I need from ALSA to play simultaneous, immediate sounds in my game?

Tags: linux, audio, mmap, alsa

I'm new to ALSA and I've managed to get PCM sound played in SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED mode. My problem is that I just can't find a way to make that mode useful for what I'm trying to do. (If someone can tell me how, I'll be glad to read). I've been reading there is this MMAP mode, but it's not as easy to find simple examples for it. I wonder if it is what I need and how I could implement it.

What I want to do is have my little game (a simple space shoot-up) to immediately play a sound when I shoot or get shot. If an enemy shoots while another sound is being played, the sounds should add up and saturate as necessary, but no sound event should be interrupted. In other words, I need to be able to edit the very byte that's about to be played.

In my useless attempts to try MMAP (without really knowing how it works in practice; just following vague theoretical instructions), I set up everything just like for SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED, but change it to SND_PCM_ACCESS_MMAP_INTERLEAVED. Then I call snd_pcm_avail_update, which seems to work and returns a large number of available frames. After that, I call snd_pcm_mmap_begin, passing the parameters, previously filling "frames" with a reasonable number (a 10, for example). The function fails and returns an error code -77. I haven't been able to find what that means. The areas array remains unmodified.

What does that error mean?  Where can I get a list of the errors?  How can I overcome it?  Is there a good, simple, example of how to use MMAP (or some other thing) to perform something more or less like what I'm trying to do?

I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALSA returns negative values on error. 77 is most likely EBADFD which indicates that the device is in an invalid state (under/overrun or not running at all). In case of underrun you're probably using a too low buffersize.

In any case, there's no way to modify audio data that you've already submitted to the alsa driver (snd_pcm_mmap_commit/writei/writen). The trick to have audio sound immediately is just to use very low buffer sizes, < 10ms will do. For this you'll want to use hw: devices, other device types usually add latency.

You still have to mix sounds together manually before you pass them to alsa. 
There's a nice mmap example in the comments on this question: [Alsa api: how to use mmap in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279326/alsa-api-how-to-use-mmap-in-c).

That being said, ALSA is a valid choice for this kind of application but you don't necessarily need to use memory mapping. Read/write access doesn't introduce additional latency, it just copies audio around a bit more.

Comment: Thank you. This was very useful. In case somebody finds it interesting, at the time of reading this reply, I had already figured out a way to solve my problem, but I still wasn't able to use MMAP. Still, I hadn't thought I could simply use low buffer sizes. What I did instead is use multiple handles and treat each as a "channel" to play simultaneous sounds. This answer is exactly what I was asking, though. I appreciate it.